# easylogging complied failed with ELPP_THREAD_SAFE

Tags: linux, openmp, easylogging++

I have been used easylogging with OMP, but I found it should add ELPP_THREAD_SAFE to keep thread safe, it success in win but when failed in ubuntu20.04. When I tried to add definition ELPP_THREAD_SAFE in cmakelist, it complied failed.
PS:-lpthread was also added.

Fail info:
/usr/include/c++/9/mutex:541:5: error: variable or field ??lock?? declared void
541 |     lock(_L1& __l1, _L2& __l2, _L3&... __l3)
|     ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/mutex:543:7: error: expected primary-expression before ??while??
543 |       while (true)
...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: problem caused by c++ version. finished